How to access derived type at runtime with pybind11?
I have a Base and a Derived class in C++ for which I create Python-bindings with pybind11. The base class implements a function (__repr__) in which I want to access the runtime type name of self. However, the way I do it, it just provides me the base type:
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base {};

PYBIND11_MODULE(mwe, m) {
    py::class_<Base>(m, "Base")
        .def("__repr__", [](const Base& self) {
            // want to see the runtime type (i.e. most derived)
            // of the `self` object!
            return py::type::of(py::cast(self)).attr("__name__");
        });
    py::class_<Derived, Base>(m, "Derived")
        .def(py::init<>());
}

In Python:
from mwe import Base, Derived

print(Derived())  # returns "Base", not "Derived"

How would I access the runtime type of self instead?

The second look into the documentation gave me the right hint:

In C++, a type is only considered polymorphic if it has at least one
virtual function and pybind11 will automatically recognize this

(see https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html).
That means in my case Derived is a non-polymorphic type behind a Base pointer, such that Python just sees the Base.
One way to fix this would be to add a virtual function to Base to achieve actual polymorphism, e.g.:
class Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

However, this is a change on the implementation and I still wonder whether one could achieve the intended behavior without changing Base or Derived.

Public inheritance without virtual functions rarely makes sense to begin with. Why have it?

@n.m.couldbeanAI You probably have a point, but I don't get it and I am willing to be enlightened. Do you want to say that non-polymorphic inheritance is not useful in general? Or just if you combine it with public? But how is public only relevant in case of virtual functions? Or do you just refer to my over-trivial MWE without any members?

First, non-public inheritance is a kind of containment and is OK woth ot without virtual functions. Normal (public) inheritance is designed to support subtype-based polymorphism and have limited use outside of its design space. One of the use cases is type-level programming when you are not interested in objects, only in types. I have not seen a compelling use case with objects and pointers/references. Perhaps you have one but that would be unusual.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Thanks for the response! Let's assume the subtype case, in which public inheritance makes sense. I still wonder why a virtual function in the base class would be a must. What if the things that the derived classes have in common don't need modification and thus have not to be overloaded. The derived classes can still extend the functionality with, e.g., additional member functions. Some interfaces just need the base class, others need a specific derived one. Actually, I don't have this in my code base, but I wonder what would be wrong about it.

If you see any such case you should be able to replace inheritance with containment.

@n.m.couldbeanAI: Is this really true? What if the derived classes make use of protected information? For the sake of minimal public interfaces, that seems to be a good reason for me to stay with inheritance. Secondly, I still do not get why one should do this apart from being able to. Meta: No offense at all, really, I just want to get your point!

You would use private (or perhaps protected) inheritance, which is a kind of containment. Again. if you find a compelling use case, go ahead. I have never seen one. Perhaps you can show me a book, an article, something with an example?

@n.m.couldbeanAI Thanks, I will keep our discussion in mind. Maybe, I can come back with the compelling example. Usually, I would respond to "don't do" with "not without a compelling reason". Given your reputation though, I can accept your reversal of the burden of proof ("why would you?"). There has to be something behind it, that you never came across any example and apparently even feel uncomfortable with that pattern.

The general principle is to prefer composition over inheritance, you can just web search this phrase and find tons of material.

Yes, I know and often adhere to it. Still, I don't see that it applies to subtyping. However, I feel this discussion is not leading anywhere and (given the votes) I am the annoying part in it :) Thanks for your time!
